# How to install php-filter extension on Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS?

Tags: php, repository

I'm having trouble installing php-filter extension on a Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS system.

Currently trying to install it for my php 7.2 cli version.

When I use `apt-get install php-filter` I get `Unable to locate package php-filter` response.

I've previously added `ppa:ondrej/php` repository, from which I've installed many other php extensions, but it seems like it doesn't have this one.

Any ideas how and from where to install this specific extension?

**EDIT AFTER FOUND SOLUTION**

The underlying issue was that the composer version I was using showed me a false message that the php's filter extension wasn't installed, but it was actually a faulty composer version.

By manually removing and installing a fresh composer version I was able to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you don't have it already installed? According to the [manual entry](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.installation.php) it should come with `php`

> The filter extension is enabled by default as of PHP 5.2.0. To disable the filter extension, use --disable-filter.

Maybe you have disabled it at some point.

If not then this [GitHub page](https://github.com/taobig/php-filter) might help.
There you will find these instructions:

```
php composer.phar require taobig/php-filter
```

The old Instructions (from 2009) found on [waybackmachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20080812031435/http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.installation.php) call for

```
pecl install filter
```

Comment: php -m shows that this extension is compiled but I'm not sure for which version of php it shows this (I have multiple php versions installed on the system). In `/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/` it doesn't show a filter.ini file and from what I've read, this means the extension is not installed. When I try `phpenmod filter` I get a response `Module filter ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available`. When I try your suggestion from Github I get a response `Could not open input file: composer.phar`. Any further suggestions maybe?

Comment: that error is because you don't have `composer` you will find instructions on the github page. But please note that this is not the original php-filter but simply someone's project like many others with the same or a similar name and function. There is also the option to try the original intallation method, which I will add to my original anwser.

Comment: I appreicate your help and I have upvoted your answer, but I was able to resolve the issue by removing and updating composer. The real issue behind this question was that I had a very old version of composer installed which showed an error that php-filter extension was missing, but it was actually an error in the composer version. Thank you again for your time!